# C fscanf and pointer

Tags: c, printing, struct, scanf, printf

After trying to read/write binaries failed miserably I tried to do the same thing with fscanf and fprintf and it seemed to work fine, but again .. reading doesn't work at all and once again I can't really tell why:

struct + pointer:

```
typedef struct flug
{
    int         flugnummer;
    char        flugziel[50];
    enum TAG    flugtag;
    int         flugzeit_stunde;
    int         flugzeit_minute;
    int         gateway;
    char        status[10];
    struct flug *next;
}FLUG;

typedef FLUG *ELEM_ZGR;
```

global variables:

```
enum TAG {
Sonntag,
Montag,
Dienstag,
Mittwoch,
Donnerstag,
Freitag,
Samstag
};

static ELEM_ZGR first;
char const datei[] = "ddslist.txt";
```

write:

```
int fluege_sichern() {
ELEM_ZGR curr;
FILE *fp;

curr = first;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"a+") != 0)
    {
        printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Anhaengen zu oeffnen",datei);
        PAUSE;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (curr != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp,"%d %s %d %d %d ",
            curr->flugnummer, curr->flugziel, curr->flugzeit_stunde, curr->flugzeit_minute, curr->gateway);
        fclose(fp);

        curr = curr->next;
    }

}
```

read:

```
void fluege_laden() {
ELEM_ZGR curr;
FILE *fp;

int i = 0;
curr = NULL;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"r") != 0)
    {
        printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Lesen zu oeffnen",datei);
        PAUSE;
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n\nArtikelliste\nArtikelnummer  Artikelbezeichnung  Artikelpreis");

    while (fscanf_s(fp,"%d %s %d %d %d ",
            &curr->flugnummer, curr->flugziel, &curr->flugzeit_stunde, &curr->flugzeit_minute, &curr->gateway) != EOF)
    {
           printf("\n%d %s %d %d %d ",
            curr->flugnummer, curr->flugziel, curr->flugzeit_stunde, curr->flugzeit_minute, curr->gateway);
           if (++i%10==0)
               PAUSE;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Please help me out here. Even a little hint would be a huge help.
[EDIT1]

```
void fluege_laden() {
ELEM_ZGR curr;
FILE *fp;

int i = 0;
curr = (ELEM_ZGR)malloc(sizeof(struct flug));

    if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"r") != 0)
    {
        printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Lesen zu oeffnen",datei);
        PAUSE;
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n\nArtikelliste\nArtikelnummer  Artikelbezeichnung  Artikelpreis");

    while (fscanf_s(fp,"%d %s %d %d %d ",
            &curr->flugnummer, curr->flugziel, &curr->flugzeit_stunde, &curr->flugzeit_minute, &curr->gateway) != EOF)
    {
           printf("\n%d %s %d %d %d ",
            curr->flugnummer, curr->flugziel, curr->flugzeit_stunde, curr->flugzeit_minute, curr->gateway);
           if (++i%10==0)
               PAUSE;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use useful arguments to the functions(instead of relying on global variables) , and let them return useful values, too. And: please don't typedef pointers. It will only confuse you and others. (an '*' is very nuch more readable for the experienced eye than a FLUGZEUG_ANZEIGER_TYP;

Comment: I'll do that as soon as the application works as intended. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look:

```
void fluege_laden() {
  ELEM_ZGR curr;
  FILE *fp;

  int i = 0;
  curr = NULL;  /* NULL! */
```

When loading, `curr` is `NULL`. You cannot write to a `NULL` pointer, that's undefined behavior. You need to allocate memory.

Also, consider *not* including the pointer in the `typedef`, it's hard to understand and remember that `ELEM_ZGR` is a pointer. Pointer semantics are important in C, it's best to make it clear to all readers of the code what's going on.

Comment: Uhm .. Ok I get that, but I don't know how to fix it. curr = first doesnt seem to help either.

Comment: What is first? is it defined somewhere ? Is it initialised? does it point to something useful?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didnt really put it in the first post. It's a global static variable (going to edit the first post and put it in there), but well .. in the end it's null, too. How do I do this? I'm usually programming in vb.net and it seems much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

In your read function `curr` is a typedef to a `FLUG *`, and you initialized it as `NULL`:

```
curr = NULL;
```

Then you try to access deference it in your `fscanf`:

```
while (fscanf_s(fp,"%d %s %d %d %d ", &curr->flugnummer,...
```

That's no good. If you have a pointer and you want to store something to it, you need to give it some memory:

```
curr = malloc(sizeof(FLUG));
```

Then you should be able to use it. Once you're done you'll need to call `free(curr)` to release that memory as well.

Comment: Ohh .. yea, I forgot about that, but it still doesn't work. Im going to update the initial post ..